# VS Code IntelliSense for C++ does not work if the project directory is a symlink

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, symlink, error-detection

VS Code (C++) error squiggles does not work if the project directory is a symlink (Linux).

For instance,

```
a
└── b
    └── c
        └── file.cpp
sl
└─── ─> c
```

When *sl* is a symlink to *a/b/c*, opening *sl* as a project directory prevents error squiggles from functioning properly.

Opening *a/b/c* (left), and opening *sl* (right)

[image]     [image]

The problem can be reproduced easily.

There is no specific C++ settings (all defaults from vscode and the "C/C++", "C/C++ Extension Pack", and "C/C++ Themes" extensions). I completely removed all configs and then reinstalled vscode to ensure all defaults are set.

Is there a way to fix this (config or otherwise)?

NB, About VS Code:

[image]

Comment: This is worth to post a bug report to the extension vendor. The question is not about programming, therefore rather is not for SO.

Comment: please post your version info as text (see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541). the output of `code --version` should suffice. Please also show the version of your vscode-cpptools extension.

Comment: @273K Questions about tools for programming is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is one or multiple of known issues. See the following issue tickets:

- [IntelliSense does not work if folder opened through a symbolic link #4573](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4573)

  - [Detect opening a workspace folder with a symlink on the path and output a warning message #9498](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9498)
- [Go to declaration always shows 2 files, relative and absolute paths
  #3288](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3288)

  - [Intellisense doesn't work for symlink
    #3456](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3456)

You can give those issue tickets a thumbs up reaction to show support for them and increase their prioritization, and subscribe to them to get notified of discussion and progress. <sup><sub>But please *don't* make a "me too" comment. "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup> Besides that, you can offer to contribute a fix, or wait patiently for one to come.

For your reference / learning purposes, the above issue tickets were found by googling "`github vscode cpptools issues symlink intellisense`".

---

For Clangd extension users, it also has symlink issues. For example, [clangd (vscode): Goto definition performs symlink resolution #544](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/544).