Intellisense (vscode) does not take local includePath for symlinked source file
I'm having trouble with the C++ extension for vscode. I have a workspace folder with correct includePath (.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json). I have some source files which are symlinks to external source files. When I open them, vscode does not take into account the local includePath directive and include errors occur.
The vscode bug seems to be about the reverse situation (include path in symlink not working properly).
Is this simply not supported ? Why a local symlink would not follow the local includePath directive ?

I wonder if this has the same underlying cause as https://stackoverflow.com/q/76139625/11107541 ?
